# unnest list of lists of different lengths to dataframe

Tags: r, api, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

My data is drawn from a json API. 
The structure is a follows:

- The documents structured as a list, with one entry per document.
- Each entry is another list containing the docvars, sometimes these
  docvars are also in the form of a list.
- The number of docvars is not consistent, ranging between 36 and 49 so
  not every entry has every docvar.
- Furthermore, the position of the docvars is also not consistent, for example docu[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghLve.png)][4] is sometimes 'date' and other time 'source'

I would like to unnest these lists and create a dataframe in which each document is a row and each docvar is a column, the missing docvars should be NA

```
library(rjson)

data = rjson::fromJSON(file="http://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/wds?format=json&fl=abstracts,admreg,alt_title,authr,available_in,bdmdt,chronical_docm_id,closedt,colti,count,credit_no,disclosure_date,disclosure_type,disclosure_type_date,disclstat,display_title,docdt,docm_id,docna,docty,dois,entityid,envcat,geo_reg,geo_reg,geo_reg_and_mdk,guid,historic_topic,id,isbn,ispublicdocs,issn,keywd,lang,listing_relative_url,lndinstr,loan_no,majdocty,majtheme,ml_abstract,ml_display_title,new_url,owner,pdfurl,prdln,projectid,projn,publishtoextweb_dt,repnb,repnme,seccl,sectr,src_cit,subsc,subtopic,teratopic,theme,topic,topicv3,totvolnb,trustfund,txturl,unregnbr,url_friendly_title,versiontyp,versiontyp_key,virt_coll,vol_title,volnb&str_docdt=1986-01-01&end_docdt=2000-12-31&rows=500&os=1&srt=docdt&order=desc")
```

[image: This is a screen shot of the data structure]

The are a lot of questions like this, however non of the solutions seem to work in this case. For example:

[Unnesting a list of lists in a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860380/unnesting-a-list-of-lists-in-a-data-frame-column)

```
 library(tidyverse)

 tidy <- data$documents %>% bind_rows(data$documents) %>%    # make larger sample data
 mutate_if(is.list, simplify_all) %>%    # flatten each list element internally 
 unnest()    # expand

Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 36 must be length 1, not 2
```

[Unnest one of several list columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538476/unnest-one-of-several-list-columns-in-dataframe)

["Unnesting" a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662114/unnesting-a-dataframe-in-r)

[Convert list of lists to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804560/convert-list-of-lists-to-dataframe)

[R convert list of lists to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117321/r-convert-list-of-lists-to-dataframe)

[R: How to extract a list from a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832059/r-how-to-extract-a-list-from-a-dataframe)

[Extracting data.frames from a list using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806232/extracting-data-frames-from-a-list-using-for-loop)

[R, dpylr: Converting list of lists of differing lenghts within dataframe into long format dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313377/r-dpylr-converting-list-of-lists-of-differing-lenghts-within-dataframe-into-lo)

This last one comes near but I have multiple docvars, many of which I do not know the names.

another attempt of mine was using a loop:

```
df <- data.frame() 
df_s <- data.frame() 
s=0
#Desired API

for(l in 1:100){
    print(l)
    s=s+500
    url <- paste0("http://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/wds?format=json&fl=abstracts,admreg,alt_title,authr,available_in,bdmdt,chronical_docm_id,closedt,colti,count,credit_no,disclosure_date,disclosure_type,disclosure_type_date,disclstat,display_title,docdt,docm_id,docna,docty,dois,entityid,envcat,geo_reg,geo_reg,geo_reg_and_mdk,guid,historic_topic,id,isbn,ispublicdocs,issn,keywd,lang,listing_relative_url,lndinstr,loan_no,majdocty,majtheme,ml_abstract,ml_display_title,new_url,owner,pdfurl,prdln,projectid,projn,publishtoextweb_dt,repnb,repnme,seccl,sectr,src_cit,subsc,subtopic,teratopic,theme,topic,topicv3,totvolnb,trustfund,txturl,unregnbr,url_friendly_title,versiontyp,versiontyp_key,virt_coll,vol_title,volnb&str_docdt=1986-01-01&end_docdt=2000-12-31&rows=500&os=",s,"&srt=docdt&order=desc")

    WBeLib_content = rjson::fromJSON(file= url)
    stop <- WBeLib_content$rows

    #df <- data.frame()
    for(i in 1:500 ){
        docu <- WBeLib_content$documents[i]
        df[i,1]    <- docu[[1]]$url
        df[i,2]    <- docu[[1]]$txturl
        df[i,3]    <- docu[[1]]$docdt
        df[i,4]    <- docu[[1]]$disclstat
        df[i,5]    <- docu[[1]]$disclosure_date
        df[i,6]    <- docu[[1]]$versiontyp
        df[i,7]    <- docu[[1]]$docty
        df[i,8]    <- docu[[1]]$subtopic
        df[i,9]    <- docu[[1]]$count
        df[i,10]    <- docu[[1]]$colti
        df[i,11]    <- docu[[1]]$historic_topic
        df[i,12]    <- docu[[1]]$seccl
        df[i,13]    <- docu[[1]]$lang
        df[i,14]    <- docu[[1]]$majdocty
        df[i,15]    <- docu[[1]]$owner
        df[i,16]    <- docu[[1]]$guid
        df[i,17]    <- docu[[1]]$repnb
        df[i,18]    <- docu[[1]]$admreg
        df[i,19]    <- docu[[1]]$pdfurl
        df[i,20]    <- docu[[1]]$docm_id
    }
    if(i>1){ df_s <- rbind(df,df_s) } else { df_s <- df}
}
```

Yet, as not all docvars are present for each document it's out of bounds. Orienting on position works, but the columns are no longer in order.

Comment: `for` loops are a bad idea here—if you're iterating over lists, use `lapply`/`Map` or one of their purrr equivalents. For extracting data from API responses, there's a nice package called [roomba](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/roomba) which aims to automate this process. For working with APIs, check out [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, those packages look promising. And you are right, I really need to make time to get more used to working with lapply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work for you ?

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
data = fromJSON("http://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/wds?format=json&fl=abstracts,admreg,alt_title,authr,available_in,bdmdt,chronical_docm_id,closedt,colti,count,credit_no,disclosure_date,disclosure_type,disclosure_type_date,disclstat,display_title,docdt,docm_id,docna,docty,dois,entityid,envcat,geo_reg,geo_reg,geo_reg_and_mdk,guid,historic_topic,id,isbn,ispublicdocs,issn,keywd,lang,listing_relative_url,lndinstr,loan_no,majdocty,majtheme,ml_abstract,ml_display_title,new_url,owner,pdfurl,prdln,projectid,projn,publishtoextweb_dt,repnb,repnme,seccl,sectr,src_cit,subsc,subtopic,teratopic,theme,topic,topicv3,totvolnb,trustfund,txturl,unregnbr,url_friendly_title,versiontyp,versiontyp_key,virt_coll,vol_title,volnb&str_docdt=1986-01-01&end_docdt=2000-12-31&rows=500&os=1&srt=docdt&order=desc")

df <- 
  data$documents %>%
  head(-1)       %>% # remove facet element
  transpose      %>% # transpose so each subelement is now a main element
  as_tibble      %>% # convert to table
  purrr::modify(~replace(.x,lengths(.x)==0,list(NA))) %>% # replace empty elements by list(NA) so they have length 1 too
  modify_if(~all(lengths(.x)==1),unlist) # unlist lists that contain only items of length 1
```

Only one list column remains:

```
names(df)[map_chr(df,class) == "list"]
# [1] "keywd"
```

As it contains items of length 1 or 2:

```
table(lengths(df$keywd))
#   1   2 
# 224 276
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
glimpse(df)

# Observations: 500
# Variables: 38
# $ url                  <chr> "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/903231468764970044/Attacking-rural-poverty-strategy-and-public-actions", "...
# $ available_in         <chr> "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English,French,Spanish,Portuguese", "Portuguese,Chinese,Engli...
# $ url_friendly_title   <chr> "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/903231468764970044/Attacking-rural-poverty-strategy-and-public-actions", "...
# $ new_url              <chr> "2000/12/1000476/Attacking-rural-poverty-strategy-and-public-actions", "2000/12/1000501/State-policies-and-womens-aut...
# $ guid                 <chr> "903231468764970044", "429001468753367328", "985531468746683502", "890081468757236671", "922151468776107524", "324581...
# $ disclosure_date      <chr> "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z...
# $ disclosure_type      <chr> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA...
# $ disclosure_type_date <chr> "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z...
# $ publishtoextweb_dt   <chr> "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z", "2010-07-01T00:00:00Z...
# $ docm_id              <chr> "090224b0828c737a", "090224b0828ac316", "090224b0828bd3f7", "090224b0828ac343", "090224b0828cf43d", "090224b0828cf42b...
# $ chronical_docm_id    <chr> "090224b0828c737a", "090224b0828ac316", "090224b0828bd3f7", "090224b0828ac343", "090224b0828cf43d", "090224b0828cf42b...
# $ txturl               <chr> "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/903231468764970044/text/multi-page.txt", "http://documents.worldbank.org/c...
# $ pdfurl               <chr> "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/903231468764970044/pdf/multi-page.pdf", "http://documents.worldbank.org/cu...
# $ docdt                <chr> "2000-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2000-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2000-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2000-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2000-12-31T00:00:00Z...
# $ totvolnb             <chr> "1", "1", "1", "1", "5", "1", "1", "14", "1", "1", "1", "1", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "1...
# $ versiontyp           <chr> "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", ...
# $ versiontyp_key       <chr> "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "1309935", "130993...
# $ volnb                <chr> "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "13", "4", "9", "12", "3", "2", "7", "10", "1", "6", "11"...
# $ repnme               <chr> "Attacking rural poverty : strategy and\n            public actions", "State policies and women's autonomy in\n      ...
# $ abstracts            <chr> "Poverty remains pervasive, and its\n            incidence and intensity are usually higher in rural than in\n       ...
# $ display_title        <chr> "Attacking rural poverty :\n            strategy and public actions", "State policies and women's\n            autono...
# $ listing_relative_url <chr> "/research/2000/12/1000476/attacking-rural-poverty-strategy-public-actions", "/research/2000/12/1000501/state-policie...
# $ docty                <chr> "Newsletter", "Working Paper (Numbered Series)", "Publication", "Poverty Reduction Strategy Paper (PRSP)", "Environme...
# $ subtopic             <chr> "Economic Theory & Research,Rural Settlements,Industrial Economics,Nutrition,Educational Sciences,Economic Growth,Agr...
# $ docna                <chr> "Attacking rural poverty : strategy and\n            public actions", "State policies and women's autonomy in\n      ...
# $ teratopic            <chr> "Poverty Reduction", "Education", "Energy", "Poverty Reduction", "Industry,Transport,Water Resources", NA, "Governanc...
# $ authors              <chr> "Okidegbe, Nwanze", "Zhang, Xiaodan", "Bogach, V. Susan", NA, "Carl Brothers International Inc.", "World Bank", "Mann...
# $ entityids            <chr> "000094946_01022305364180", "000094946_01022705322025", "000094946_01011005520622", "000094946_0102240538258", "00009...
# $ subsc                <chr> "Macro/Non-Trade", "Human Development", "(Historic)Other power and energy conversion", "(Historic)Macro/non-trade", "...
# $ lang                 <chr> "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "Portuguese", "English", "English", "Chinese", "English", "Eng...
# $ historic_topic       <chr> "Poverty Reduction", "Education", "Energy", "Poverty Reduction", "Industry,Transport,Water Resources", NA, "Governanc...
# $ seccl                <chr> "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public...
# $ sectr                <chr> "(Historic)Economic Policy", "(Historic)Multisector", "(Historic)Electric Power & Other Energy", "(Historic)Economic ...
# $ majdocty             <chr> "Publications & Research", "Publications & Research", "Publications,Publications & Research", "Country Focus", "Proje...
# $ src_cit              <chr> "Rural development note. -- No. 6 (December 2000)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
# $ keywd                <list> [[["Rural Poor;medium term expenditure\n            framework;rural poverty reduction strategy;rural\n            ar...
# $ owner                <chr> "Environ & Soc Sustainable Dev VP (ESD)", "Off of Sr VP Dev Econ/Chief Econ (DECVP)", "Energy & Mining Sector Unit (E...
# $ repnb                <chr> "21649", "21743", "WTP492", "21834", "E287", "27779", "21604", "E425", "21604", "22194", "21837", "22903", "E425", "E...
```

Comment: Thank you! That works well. I pasted your code in my total loop, so that I can use bindrow to add each page into the dataframe. `if(l == 1) { df_s <- df}  else { df_s <- bind_rows(df,df_s) }`  However, the 15th page I get `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `lndinstr` can't be converted from character to list`. I think because 'lndinstr' is a list which is present in df_s but not in df. Do you know a solution? Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: you should make a list of those data.frames, using lapply on a vector of api requests, then use bind_rows on those, it will be more efficient. I believe your error comes from the fact I "simplify" the list columns when they have only elements of length one. It seems to me that column `Indinstr` contains sometimes objects of length one, and sometimes more

Comment: I suggest you remove the last instruction : `modify_if(~all(lengths(.x)==1),unlist)` so you have list columns everywhere and the `bind_rows` should work smoothly, then apply this last instruction on the resulting data.frame

Comment: you'll find them that `keywd` is not the only remaining list column